# Is there a way to stop changes to certain file types invalidating a successful build?

Tags: bitbucket-server

I'd like to not have to re-run the build if I change an `.md` file, for instance. My documentation change isn't going to break the build.

Comment: What is your continuous integration system? Jenkins?

Comment: Yeah, Jenkins. ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. It might require security changes (for the `getPreviousBuild` script). This isn't fully tested at this point, I will update if it changes.

This will check if the commit contains any files that are not `.md` files and either run the build or pass the build if the last build was successful.

```
  stage('Check for doc only commit') {
            environment {
                LAST_BUILD = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (LAST_BUILD && LAST_BUILD.getResult().toString() == "SUCCESS") {
                        echo "the previous build ${LAST_BUILD.getId()} passed, checking for a docs-only commit"
                        NON_DOC_COUNT = sh(
                                script: 'git show --pretty="format:" --name-only | grep -v -e \'.md\' | wc -l',
                                returnStdout: true
                        ).trim()
                        if (NON_DOC_COUNT.toInteger() == 0) {
                            echo "Found no non-document files in the last commit and previous build was a pass, returning success result"
                            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```